# dotPeek symbol server not providing source code to VS2013 debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, symbol-server, dotpeek

My understanding of dotPeek symbol server feature is as follows:

Whenever IDE asks for debugging information on a given assembly dotPeek decompiles the assembly and symbols (+ decompiled source code?) back to IDE.

Yet my experience is as follows:

After configuring my IDE and checking the Output window when debugging I see that symbols for all managed assemblies are being loaded. I can step into these libraries / .NET platform and debug there with no problems.

But there is this one 3rd party assembly which I have problems with. Output window prints this during startup of my application:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9bc23327\4940c90d\assembly\dl3\8fde229b\401c97fd_0937d001\WebApi.Hal.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

But when I try to step into the class of WebApi.Hal IDE asks me for a source code file and Output prints this:

```
SRCSRV: The module 'C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9bc23327\4940c90d\assembly\dl3\8fde229b\401c97fd_0937d001\WebApi.Hal.dll' does not contain source server information.
```

Configuration:

Options -> Debugging -> Symbols:

Three configured Symbol servers in this order

http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols

http://localhost:33417/

Options -> Debugging -> General screenshot:

[image: Options -> Debugging -> General screenshot]

What am I missing?

Comment: This appears like a more general issue as I'm having the same issue loading source for an assembly that's on symbolsource.org, though when not running through IISExpress it loads fine.